Best way to handle returning success (i.e. 20X) responses AND failure (i.e. 4XX, 5XX etc..) responses in Java Spring Boot?
I know within the Spring @RestController class, we can do something like:
@GetMapping("/"
public ResponseEntity<Weather> getWeatherRecordsById(@PathVariable Integer id){
   mySpringDataJPARepository.findById(id)
      .map(res -> new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.Ok)
      .orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NotFound);

However, this seems to manual/verbose - Is there a more efficient way for handling successful and failed HTTP responses, when you need unique responses/HTTP codes returned to the user/client? Spring AOP/Aspect Orientated Programming and Advices?

This question is similar to: What is the best way to return different types of ResponseEntity in Spring-Boot (Error Handling for REST with Spring). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I prefer create new responseDto record or pojo that has three field int status, Object data and String message this record is used for every return type whether it is success or error, in this way we have some well defined structure across multiple controller.

ResponseEntity is ancient. Dunno why people keep recommending it. Current Spring / Spring Boot way is that your method handler just returns the object (in your case, Weather), and for error cases, you throw a ResponseStatusException. If you return your object, it gets translated to a 200. And ResponseStatusException gets translated to the error code you specify.

ResponseEntity isn't ancient, it gives you more control over what to return next to just the object.

Use ResponseEntity.of which takes an optional and automatically returns a 404 if the optional is empty. So something along return mySpringDataJPARepository.findById(id).map(ResponseEntity::of); should do the trick.

@M.Deinum "it gives you more control over what to return next to just the object" ... such as?

headers, content type etc. You don't have this control when throwing an exception.

@M.Deinum Better read the docs closer. Of course ResponseStatusException lets you add headers. Seeing as MethodNotAllowedException is one class that's derived from ResponseStatusException and does just that -- hint, hint.

You are right that is as of Spring 5.1 before that it wasn't possible. NOnetheless imho it is nicer to just return a value instead of throwing an exception. But we can agree to disagree on that.

@M.Deinum do you code your methods to return -1/false vs. throwing IllegalArgumentException? Same diff. Every Java lib in the universe throws exceptions for error cases vs. returning special values. That's on chapter 1, page 1, paragraph 1, sentence 1 of every Java book :). In fact, even the answer down below that got down voted relies on throwing an exception! so his argument makes zero sense since he's contradicting himself.

Exceptions are for exceptional cases, what exceptional cases are we can debate. I think not finding a record is not an exception case and for that you shouldn't throw an exception but properly handle it. If it is something that can happen during regular flow. In my book exceptions are for exceptional cases not for these things, but as said we probably have different opinions on what exceptional cases are.

@M.Deinum by your own definition of "they're for exceptional cases" (which isn't entirely accurate) ... does your API have a > 50% not found rate? If yes, then your API is poorly designed or your users are improperly using it to have such a high miss rate. If no, then it would fall under your "exceptional case" rule, no? :)

There is no general rule for when not found is exceptional or not. Depends on the api, the use case etc. A single not-found can be exceptional or not, the same for 80% misses. It all depends. There is no single right or wrong answer.

The thing is you need  to have proper exception/error handling strategy.
Which means managing checked and unchecked exception.
Then you need to create a global exception handler using @AdviceController annotation, where you match Exception with expected Responses with their Http Status.
It's not just about AOP, or Spring, it's about error handling, or exception handling strategy.
In example :
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(WeatherNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> weatherNotFoundHandler(WeatherNotFoundException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorDetails("Weather Not Found", ex.getMessage()), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    
    // Additional exception handlers can be defined here for different types of exceptions
}

When adding advice controller, you will not need even to use the orElse your controller will become :
@GetMapping("/"
public ResponseEntity<Weather> getWeatherRecordsById(@PathVariable Integer id){
   new ResponseEntity<>(mySpringDataJPARepository.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK); 
}


Use ResponseEntity.of(Optional) and you don't need the exception at all. It will automatically return a NOT_FOUND for an empty optional and an OK with body if it isn't.

This still needs handling the exception inside the controller, and it's not clean design compliant. It's better to have proper exception handling strategy.

It doesn't require exception handling. the findById returns an Optional it will not throw an exception if nothing is found. Your case as depected here requires optional handing with an orElseThrow(() -> new WeatherNotFoundException(). else your exception handling is useless.

@M.Deinum you're still missing my point and focusing on one detail. I am sorry not sorry but you saying this is thing that is useless.
With global exception handler you don't need to modify the controller, if your return ResponseEntity.of(Optional) where is your readability ? How will you know expected exceptions that can potentially be thrown ? You're focusing on one detail, and just saying it is useless. The fact that you ignored what i said about proper exception handling strategy, makes your explanation narrow and useless.
And no, it doesn't require explicitely throwing the exception.

Yes it does require explicit throwing, your WeatherNotFoundException won't magically get into existence, just because there is an @ExceptionHandler for it.. Yes I'm only focussing on the case as asked by the starter of this question. Exception handling is for exceptional cases, not finding something isn't an exceptional case in my book. Your code doesn't show possible throwable exceptions either (and no having to plough through a list of @ExceptionHandler annotated methods or spread over classes doesn't qualify in my book). Adding too narrow @ExceptionHandler is just overkill.

If it's thrown in the Service layer, it doesn't need to be explicitely handled in the controller. For the love of god, stop being narrow minded and just saying everything is useless.

And yes, i will say it again, the point of this discussion, is to have knowledge transfer, so i will repeat it again, global strategy of error handling and exception handling combined with global exception handler is very useful, and not deprecated.
Stop throwing words randomely. I don't know where you read it was deprecated.

You aren't calling a service layer, and moving things down to the service layer doesn't improve the fact you need to handle it. I never said it was deprecated so stop confusing me with someone else or point fingers at me for things I didn't say. I nowhere said global exception handling is useless that is your assumption that I mean that. You shouldn't throw exception to handle non exceptional cases, if an entity isn't found it isn't found that doesn't have to be exceptional. Also you shouldn't throw specific EntityXYZNotFoundException as that will explode.

@M.Deinum You just keep focusing on one detail, and no you’re wrong, there is no hard written rule about entities not found. I will repeat it again, it’s better to have global exception handler with list of possible exception with proper strategy. If it doesn’t qualify in your book, well it’s up to you.
You still ignore everything I wrote before.
